# Why am I getting numbers outside the range I passed?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to c++ and I do not understand why the numbers are outside the range. I
commented 
where I thought you initial the range

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;

int main()
{

 vector<int> deck;
 default_random_engine eng(time(0));
```

I thought here was where I specify the range of the random numbers but instead I get 
numbers outside that range

```
 uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, 51);

 int pos1;
 int pos2;
 int num1;
 int num2;
 int i;
 int n;
 int m;

 for (i = 1; i < 53; i++)
 {
     deck.push_back(i);

 }

 pos1 = dis(eng);
 pos2 = dis(eng);

 num1 = deck.at(pos1);
 num2 = deck.at(pos2);


 for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
 {
     pos1 = dis(eng);
     pos2 = dis(eng);

     cout << pos1 << "\n" << pos2;

 }




 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks that the problem is in the last line `cout << pos1 << "\n" << pos2;` (here you forgot to add `<< "\n"`). So if your program prints four numbers (e.g. 22, 23, 24, 25) you will see following text:

```
22
2324
25
```

So number 2324 will be outside your range, but actually it is concatenation of two numbers.